# Entropy and the probability to guess

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and suppose that we choose a random value $X=x_1$.
Let $A$ be an event such that $H[ X \mid  A] = k$, where 
$$H[X \mid A] = - \sum_{x} P[X =x \mid A] \log_2( P[X =x \mid A]).$$

Is it correct to interpret the entropy bound by saying that, after having observed $A$, the probability of guessing $x_1$ is at most $2^{-k}$? This seems to be true when $X$ is uniformly distributed, but is there such a lower bound in general?

Comment: This problem is incomplete, is what is the alphabet set for $X$, i mean that are there any other possible values for $X$ or it is degenerate and takes only value $x_1$.

Comment: @ShahidMShah: The alphabet set should not matter: In the case when $X$ has only $1$ element, the entropy $H[X \mid A]$ is $0$ (no matter what $A$ is, and $2^{-0}=1$ is trivially true, right?

Comment: "the probability of guessing x_1" What does that mean? Probability of guessing in one try? Why don't you try to make sense of that without the conditioning?

Comment: @leonbloy: It means, someone chooses an element $x_1$ in advance via some probability distribution (but doesn't tell you about $x_1$). What is the probability of guessing $x_1$ correctly? What is the probability of guessing $x_1$ correctly when I tell you about some event $A$ that reduces the entropy of $X$ (regarding $x_1$)  to some $k$?

Comment: The standard relation between entropy and probability of good/bad guessing is given by the Fano inequality